# Codeigniter - Concat query

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, concatenation

So I have this table

```
EMP_ID     SECTION       TEST     SAMPLE_NAME   QUANTITY
 1001     molecular       reo         heart         3
 1001     molecular       reo         spleen        4
```

This is my MODEL code for it.

```
$query = $this->db->select('section, quantity,test,sample_name')
            ->from('tblmastersection')
            ->where('emp_id', $emp_id)
            ->order_by("save_section_id", "asc")
            ->join('tblsavesection', 'tblmastersection.section_id = tblsavesection.section_id', 'inner')
            ->join('tbljoinedtests', 'tblsavesection.test_id = tbljoinedtests.test_id', 'inner')
            ->join('tblmastersample', 'tblsavesection.samp_id = tblmastersample.samp_id', 'inner')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
```

What I want to do is to make it like this..

```
EMP_ID     SECTION       TEST       SAMPLE_NAME        QUANTITY
 1001     molecular       reo       heart, spleen         7
```

rows with the same `EMP_ID` will concat and the quantity will be sum up.
Someone please help me to redesign my code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you can change to sql Select like this:

```
SELECT EMP_ID,sum(QUANTITY) QUANTITY , STUFF(( SELECT  ','+ SAMPLE_NAME FROM TableName a
WHERE b.EMP_ID = a.EMP_ID FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1, '')  Members
FROM TableName b
GROUP BY EMP_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've already made an SQL-SERVER query that answers my question. My problem now is converting it to a codeigniter model query code....

Here's my sql query....

```
SELECT section, test, samp_id = 
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + sample_name
       FROM tblsavesection 
       inner join tblmastersample
       on tblsavesection.samp_id = tblmastersample.samp_id
       WHERE emp_id = '1' AND tblsavesection.test_id = tbljoinedtests.test_id
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
      ,SUM(quantity)as Quantity
FROM tblsavesection
inner join TblJoinedTests
on TblSaveSection.test_id = TblJoinedTests.test_id
inner join Tblmastersection
on TblSaveSection.section_id = Tblmastersection.section_id
GROUP BY test, section, tbljoinedtests.test_id
```

Thanks! =)